# Как в phpstorm перейти к следующей точки редактирования кода?

Tags: phpstorm

Как называется действие, на которой можно задать горячие клавиши, чтобы перейти к следующей точки редактирования кода. 
Вот, что я имею в виду: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В sublime text можно перейти к следующей точки с помощью горячих клавиш, а в storm таких не нашел. Но тут вот появляется такая красная линия, вот как ее вызвать?

Comment: в настройках можно задать горячие клавиши

Comment: Понятно, а к какому действию? Если отвечаете, то не поленитесь, выдать ответ до конца.